# Image fields are uploading php and other files to upload folder

Tags: php, mysql

My script is not working properly. If i upload a php file instead of jpg file then it should not upload php files to upload folder, i want to allow only image files. Please correct my script.

Here is my code Thanks !

```
<?php
include "inc.php";
ob_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['ocer']) && trim($_SESSION['ocer'])!=''){
header("Location: admin.php?l=1");
}


function getExtension($str) {
         $i = strrpos($str,".");
         if (!$i) { return ""; }
         $l = strlen($str) - $i;
         $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
         return $ext;
 }


$title=addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']));
$des=addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['des']));
$location=addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['location']));
$state=addslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['state']));
$status=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['status']);
$userid=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['userid']);
$date1=mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['date1']);



chmod('upload', 0777);


if($_FILES['file_name1']['name']!="")
{
    $file_name1=$_FILES['file_name1']['name'];

    $ext=getExtension($file_name1);
    if(trim($ext)=='jpeg' || trim($ext)=='jpg' || trim($ext)=='gif' || trim($ext)=='png' || trim($ext)=='tiff')
    {
        $file_name1=mktime().'thumb1'.'.'.$ext;

        copy($_FILES['file_name1']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$file_name1);
    }
} 

if($_FILES['file_name2']['name']!="")
{
    $file_name2=$_FILES['file_name2']['name'];

    $ext=getExtension($file_name2);
    if(trim($ext)=='jpeg' || trim($ext)=='jpg' || trim($ext)=='gif' || trim($ext)=='png' || trim($ext)=='tiff')
    {

    $file_name2=mktime().'thumb2'.'.'.$ext;

    copy($_FILES['file_name2']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$file_name2);
    }
} 

if($_FILES['file_name3']['name']!="")
{
    $file_name3=$_FILES['file_name3']['name'];

    $ext=getExtension($file_name3);
    if(trim($ext)=='jpeg' || trim($ext)=='jpg' || trim($ext)=='gif' || trim($ext)=='png' || trim($ext)=='tiff')
    {

    $file_name3=mktime().'thumb3'.'.'.$ext;

    copy($_FILES['file_name3']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$file_name3);
    }
} 

if($_FILES['file_name4']['name']!="")
{
    $file_name4=$_FILES['file_name4']['name'];

    $ext=getExtension($file_name4);
    if(trim($ext)=='jpeg' || trim($ext)=='jpg' || trim($ext)=='gif' || trim($ext)=='png' || trim($ext)=='tiff')
    {

    $file_name4=mktime().'thumb4'.'.'.$ext;

    copy($_FILES['file_name4']['tmp_name'],"upload/".$file_name4);
    }
}

if(trim($title)!="" && trim($des)!=""){


$sql_ins="insert into `jobs` set title='$title',des='$des',location='$location',state='$state',date1='$date1',userid='$userid',status='$status',newsimg='$file_name1',newsimg2='$file_name2',newsimg3='$file_name3',newsimg4='$file_name4'";


$rs=mysql_query($sql_ins) or die(mysql_error());

$lid=mysql_insert_id();

$notice="job";


}


header("location: admin.php?done=1");


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following lines

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["file_name3"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext...)// your if else condition
{}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 :

```
$valid_mime_types = array(
  "image/gif",
  "image/png",
  "image/jpeg",
  "image/pjpeg",
);

if (in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $valid_mime_types)) {
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
}
```

Part 2 :

```
$valid_file_extensions = array(".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif", ".png");

$file_extension = strrchr($_FILES["file"]["name"], ".");

// Check that the uploaded file is actually an image
// and move it to the right folder if is.
if (in_array($file_extension, $valid_file_extensions)) {
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
}
```

Part 3 :

```
if (@getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]) !== false) {
  $destination = "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
}
```